# Leetcode Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock with Transaction Fee, How to think in it

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I understand the solution to Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock with Transaction Fee, and other 5 problems relative to Stock Sell. I just want deep understanding of how to come up with such recursive relation in problems alike.

I have read https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock-with-transaction-fee/discuss/108870/most-consistent-ways-of-dealing-with-the-series-of-stock-problems and I understand entirely.

But, I am having trouble resolving some similar problem with minor changes, such as if one can buy stock without sell those previously bought first.

So, what is the general approach on coming up with correct recursive relation?

I am really confused. Thank you so much

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, sorry for misleading. i meant like 1. buy stock A; 2. buy stock B; 3. sell stock A; 4 sell stock B

Comment: "if one can buy stock without sell those previously bought": sounds like a "within budget" question...

Comment: There is no magical recipe that will make you solve such questions. There is a sequence of steps that you need to make whatever the type of the problem. Check the input -> write few test cases -> write naive solution -> write test cases to fail your own solution -> start to relate to any of the known algorithms like DP or so . You can get multiple solutions to the same problem. Go back and forth and leave the problem then come back to it to solve it again. You will get better by practice

Comment: maybe take a look at this: https://note.tianhaoz.com/fucking-interview/online-assessment/leetcode/121-best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock.html

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 cases for the problem

Case 1 : When I  have a stock on day i, represented as dp[i][1], select max of below 2 points

```
 case 1a : I bought it today.
dp[i][1] = dp[i-1][0]-prices[i]-fee

 case 1b : I am carrying a pre-bought stock
dp[i][1] = dp[i-1][1]
```

Case 2 : When I do not have a stock on day i, represented as dp[i][0]

```
case 2a : I sold it today
dp[i][0] = dp[i-1][1]+prices[i]

 case 2b : I sold the stock at some other previous day, doing nothing
dp[i][0] = dp[i-1][0]
```

Following is the code in c#

```
public int MaxProfit(int[] prices, int fee) {
        int n = prices.Length;
        if(n<=1)
            return 0;
        int[,] dp=new int[n,2];
        dp[0,0] = 0;
        dp[0,1] = -prices[0]-fee;
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            dp[i,0] = Math.Max(dp[i-1,0],dp[i-1,1] + prices[i]);
             dp[i,1] = Math.Max(dp[i-1,1],dp[i-1,0]-prices[i]-fee);
        }
        return dp[n-1,0];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Say the given array is:

[7, 1, 5, 3, 6, 4]

If we plot the numbers of the given array on a graph, we get:

Profit Graph

The points of interest are the peaks and valleys in the given graph. We need to find the largest peak following the smallest valley. We can maintain two variables - minprice and maxprofit corresponding to the smallest valley and maximum profit (maximum difference between selling price and minprice) obtained so far respectively.

```
class Solution {
  public int maxProfit(int[] prices) {
     int max = 0;
     int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

     for(int i = 0 ; i < prices.length ; i++) {
        if(prices[i] < min) {
            min = prices[i];
        }else {
            max = Math.max(max, prices[i] - min);
        }
     }

     return max; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Solution {
   public int maxProfit(int[] prices, int fee) {
    if (prices == null || prices.length <= 1) {
        return 0;
    } 
    long profit = 0, minPrice = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    //Integer.MIN_VALUE = - 2147483648

  for (int price : prices) {
    long profit_old = profit;
    profit = Math.max(profit, minPrice + price - fee);
    minPrice = Math.max(minPrice, profit_old - price);  
   }  

  return (int)profit;

  }
}
```

Your Input [1,3,2,8,4,9] 2

see how Profit & minPrice value gets updated in code

profit  0.
minPrice -1

profit 0
minPrice -1

profit 0
minPrice -1

profit 5
minPrice -1

profit 5
minPrice 1

profit 8
minPrice 1

So Final  MaxProfit is 8.